# Shutdown and restart problem in Ubuntu 13.10 - Problema en apagado y reinicio en Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: shutdown

After installing updates and making changes to Ubuntu - when I shutdown or restart - when I am turning off the system it stays there loading and does not completely shut down.

So what I do is forcibly shut with the button on the PC. What do you need to help solve this? How do I fix it?

> #### Original Question in Spanish:
>
> Después de estar instalando actualizaciones y haciendo cambios en
> Ubuntu a la hora de apagarlo o reiniciarlo cuando se esta apagando se
> queda ahí cargando y no se termina de apagar. Entonces o que hago es
> apagarlo forzadamente con el boton de la pc. ¿A que se puede deber
> esto? ¿Como lo soluciono?

Comment: Please provide an English translation of your question. This is primarily an English site and we can hardly help you if we don't understand your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't forcibly shutdown your system. If it's doing stuff, you wait till it ends. Especially if it's applying upgrades. This is because your system can be left in an inconsistent state and break something really badly.

So, how to fix it? Start installing the upgrades yourself, should be a good start.